# Автоматическое добавление слайдов

Tags: слайдер

У меня вопрос такой: на сайте есть блок логотипов партнеров. Хотим организовать его через слайдер, но пока неизвестно точное количество логотипов.
Если в слайдере они (логотипы) планируются листаться по три штуки (три логотипа на одном слайде), то возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при добавлении нового логотипа, который не помещается в предыдущий слайд, новый слайд с ним создавался автоматически?
Например, сейчас у нас три логотипа. Слайдер не листается. Но как только мы добавим четвертый, автоматически добавится второй слайд. Когда добавится седьмой логотип, то автоматически появится третий слайд и т.д.?

Comment: Коротко, в стиле вопроса: можно. Далее - смотреть, как у вас организован слайдер, как туда добавляются элементы и т.д. и т.п.